# Union all 2 different tables

Tags: sql-server

Basically I have 2 tables

-dbo.TicketSales
-dbo.Expenses

In my dbo.Expenses table i have a query that actually works:

```
WITH Aggregates AS
        (
            SELECT 
                 CONVERT(date, Expenses_Date) AS [Date]
                ,Expenses.Expenses_Desc AS [Description]
                ,Expenses.Expenses_Remarks AS [Remarks]
                ,SUM(Expenses.Expenses_Amount) AS [Total Expenses]
            FROM dbo.Expenses
            GROUP BY CONVERT(date, Expenses_Date),Expenses.Expenses_Desc,Expenses.Expenses_Remarks
        )
        SELECT
            E.[Date],
            E.[Description],
            E.[Remarks],
            E.[Total Expenses]
        FROM
            Aggregates AS E
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            [Date] = NULL,
            [Description] = NULL,
            [Remarks] = 'CURRENT TOTAL EXPENSES',
            [Total Expenses] = SUM(E.[Total Expenses]) 
        FROM
            Aggregates AS E
```

My Problem is, How to GET the SUM of dbo.TicketSales.TotalMoney and Union 
it to my existing result ?

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4jcc.png)

Comment: Just add another `UNION ALL` for `SUM(dbo.TicketSales.TotalMoney)` just like `expenses`

Comment: @AjayGupta, do have to use innerjoin ?please see image ive included

Comment: `Inner Join` to? Depends entirely on your requirement. If you just want to sum all the Ticket Sales then you can simply add another `UNION ALL` to the existing query.

Comment: @AjayGupta, TicketSales is a different table, how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comments, I think this is what you want:

```
WITH Aggregates AS
        (
            SELECT 
                 CONVERT(date, Expenses_Date) AS [Date]
                ,Expenses.Expenses_Desc AS [Description]
                ,Expenses.Expenses_Remarks AS [Remarks]
                ,SUM(Expenses.Expenses_Amount) AS [Total Expenses]
            FROM dbo.Expenses
            GROUP BY CONVERT(date, Expenses_Date),Expenses.Expenses_Desc,Expenses.Expenses_Remarks
        )
        SELECT
            E.[Date],
            E.[Description],
            E.[Remarks],
            E.[Total Expenses]
        FROM
            Aggregates AS E
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            [Date] = NULL,
            [Description] = NULL,
            [Remarks] = 'CURRENT TOTAL EXPENSES',
            [Total Expenses] = SUM(E.[Total Expenses]) 
        FROM
            Aggregates AS E
        UNION ALL
        Select
            [Date] = NULL,
            [Description] = NULL,
            [Remarks] = 'CURRENT MONEY',
            [Total Expenses] = SUM(TotalMoney) 
        FROM
            TicketSales
        UNION ALL
        Select
            [Date] = NULL,
            [Description] = NULL,
            [Remarks] = 'DIFFERENCE',
            [Total Expenses] = (
                                 (Select SUM(TotalMoney) from TicketSales)
                                -(Select SUM(E.[Total Expenses]) from Aggregates AS E)
                               )
```

Comment: How to get the difference ? please see included image.

Comment: @Jerwen Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. have a little problem here when returning the difference it is populating the column

DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
E 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900
DIFFERENCE 2241900

Comment: Youre a God ! Thanks !